# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'commit'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

1) create database

```py
store=sqlite3.connect("store . d b ")
c r =store .cursor()
c r .execute("create table if not exists store (salaries string, price integer ,numbers integer, Barcode integer primary key autoincrement)")
c r. execute("create table if not exists ban too (salaries  string  , price integer ,numbers  integer ,barcode  integer,"
           "foreign key (barcode) references store(Barcode))")
c r. execute("create table if not exists shirt (salaries  string  , price integer ,numbers  integer ,barcode  integer,"
           "foreign key (barcode) references store(Barcode))")
```

2) Create 3 functions to doing jobs in GUI (note GUI code not here but the the syntax error in commit but in first time the commit is doing job but now  I don't know what happen it's not doing job)

3) This number one of this function

```py
def store():
    A0 = a .get()
    B0 = b .get()
    C0 = c .get()
    c r .execute("insert  into store (salaries ,price, numbers) values(?,?,?)", (A0, B0, C0))
    sav ty ()
```

4) This number two of function its take elements to save it in table ban too

```py
def bantoo0():
    c r. execute("insert  into ban too (salaries ,price ,numbers ,barcode ) select salaries, price ,numbers ,Barcode from store ")
    cr. execute("select salaries ,price ,numbers, barcode, min( row id ) from ban too ")
    cr. execute("delete from ban too where row id not in (select min(row id)from ban too group by salaries, price, numbers ,barcode )")
    sav ty()
```

5) Function numbers 3 making same ban too but the between table

```py
def shirt0():
    c r. execute("insert  into shirt (salaries, price , numbers ,barcode) select salaries ,price ,numbers ,Barcode from store ")
    c r. execute("select salaries ,price ,numbers ,barcode, min(row id) from shirt ")
    c r. execute("delete from shirt where row id not in (select min(row id)from shirt group by salaries ,price ,numbers ,barcode )")
    sav ty()
```

6) Here it problem this code in past making job to saving the data in tables but now not

```py
def sav ty():
    store . commit ()
```

Comment: NOTE: the problem in commit()

Comment: Why are there so many extraneous spaces in your code?